# Updating a textview periodically in android

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm currently developing an android application. It needs to update a textview value periodically.

For instance, I want to increase the value by 10 each second.
I tried with the following code, but it is not working fine : the textview is only updated after the increment is finished

```
package com.example.stack1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        TextView output=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        output.setText(String.valueOf(0));
        System.out.println(0);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        output.setText(String.valueOf(10));
        System.out.println(10);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        output.setText(String.valueOf(20));
        System.out.println(20);
    }
}
```

`output` is a textview in main.xml file. This file only contains this object.

Note- Expected output in textview is "0", after 10 second "10" after 20 seconds "20". However, with this code, the output is blank until 20 seconds , then "20" appears.

Comment: it seems simple. but im not getting the required output. Above is not my whole application. Above is just a basic code to test and I have to develop further and further. So help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to use something like [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) instead of `sleep()` as `sleep()` will stop everything going on in the process during the sleep time.

The reason it's not showing anything is that you're doing it in the `onResume()` method. So when it loads up the display, before it actually shows anything, it's processing that method to get things set up for the user.

So, what you want is:

1. Load display with value 0
2. Wait 10 seconds
3. Increment and display to user
4. Wait 10 seconds
5. Increment and display to user

What you're getting because of the `sleep()` commands is:

1. Set value to 0
2. Wait 10 seconds
3. Set value to 10
4. Wait 10 seconds
5. Set value to 20
6. Display value

With an AlarmManager, you initialise that in your `onResume()` method, the display loads, then the AlarmManager increments the value every ten seconds.

Comment: Ill try. Understood the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1643617 You're welcome. You should be able to find some tutorials for using AlarmManager by Googling. [This one](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129) doesn't seem too bad, nor does [this one](http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html). You'll need to pass the alarm service either a copy of the activity (with a way of changing the TextView content), or a copy of the TextView itself, so it can change the values.

Comment: I haven't used alarm manager. Can anyone Help with a simple example?? It will be a great help.

Comment: I've posted some example links in my previous comment. You'll either want to create your own `TextView` class that implements `Parcelable` or use a `Handler` to pass it. The example I worked from to create my code that does something similar was a ksoap2 example one of my colleagues had started hacking, so I don't know where it came from unfortunately.